# How can we modify existing db password on re-apply terraform RDS instances?

Tags: terraform, devops, amazon-rds, aws-devops

I am creating a new aws_db_instance and after terraform deployment
I want to update my master password.

[image]
when I pass a new password using a variable or as a string.
But when I apply then destroy rds and recreate instance.

How can we modify only RDS DB instance password using terraform?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding [lifecycle](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle) policies? You should be able to delete an instance as long as there's more than one in the cluster. Try adding `create_before_destroy` to avoid cluster getting destroyed when you replace the only instance in the cluster.

Comment: it's not a policy issue but existing DB imported into terraform and volume is encrypted. and after, all code configures DB volume must require encrypted.

Comment: Those are not AWS lifecycle policies, those are for Terraform to alter the default behaviour to make it suitable for your needs. If you're importing existing stuff created outside of Terraform, then like Mark B said, you'll need to make sure everything matches identically. In your case, I'd assume you only have 1 instance in your cluster as Terraform throws cluster destroy error. RDS clusters need a min of 1 instance to always run before it attempts to delete the cluster. To avoid that, you can instruct terraform to create before delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot, you have modified the `storage_encrypted` value, from `true` to `null` (false). Terraform is very clearly telling you that is the reason it is replacing the instance.